# I need to display the highest and lowest sales values

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I need to create a program that enters daily sales for each day of the week. Once the values are entered I need to be able to display:

```
Sales for day 1 are ###

Sales for day 2 are ###

The lowest sales was XXX

The highest sales was XXX
```

The problem is that I can't get my code to cout:

```
Sales for day 1 are XXX

Sales for day 2 are XXX
```

All I can get it to say is

```
Sales are:

XXX

XXX

XXX
```

And I also don't know how to find the lowest and the highest sales. We haven't even begun working with MIN & MAX functions so I'm lost as to how to accomplish it.

My code that I have so far is:

```
const int DAYS_SALES = 7;
double sales[DAYS_SALES];
int sub;
double min = 0;
double max = 0;

for(sub = 0; sub < DAYS_SALES; ++sub)
{
    cout << "Enter in the sales for day " << (sub + 1) << " ";
    cin >> sales[sub];
}
cout << endl << "The sales for day are: " << endl;
for (sub = 0; sub < DAYS_SALES; ++sub)
    cout << sales[sub] << " " << endl;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Track the min and max values as your for loop goes over each value.

If the current value (`sales[sub]`) is less than the `min` so far, store that value as the new minimum value.

```
const int DAYS_SALES = 7;
double sales[DAYS_SALES];
int sub;
double min = 0.0;
double max = 0.0;

for(sub = 0; sub < DAYS_SALES; ++sub)
{
    cout << "Enter in the sales for day " << (sub + 1) << " ";
    cin >> sales[sub];
}

min = sales[0];
max = sales[0];

cout << endl << "The sales for day are: " << endl;
for (sub = 0; sub < DAYS_SALES; ++sub)
{
    cout << endl << "The sales for day are: " << sales[sub] << " " << endl;

    if (sales[sub] < min)
    {   // If we find a smaller min. value, store that in min
        min = sales[sub];
    }

    if (sales[sub] > max)
    {   // If we find a bigger max. value, store that in max
        max = sales[sub];
    }
}

// Print out the Min and Max that we found.
cout<< "The lowest sales was " << min;
cout<< "The highest sales was " << max <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe you should enter your values to a `std::vector` of the appropriate type and then call `std::minmax(...)` on it.